# Jump out of code if a button is pressed

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Is there some way to have a 'listener' of sorts to listen for a button click in the middle of code?  There are certain scenarios where I won't have to wait for the code to complete before I can exit the functions but I cannot seem to find a way to see if the button was clicked other than throwing a ton of if checks throughout the function calls which doesn't seem very efficient to me.

Comment: Use a [`BackgroundWorker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker(v=vs.110).aspx) or a [Cancellable Task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Basically that's exactly what you have to do (at least if you want to follow good practices). It's not necessary to have tons of checks; a single check at a strategically selected point that gets evaluated a few times per second will do just fine. `BackgroundWorker` and cancellable tasks both require the "task" to cooperate, i.e. run checks and yield if told to do so.

Comment: Threading is certainly the "proper" way to do this, but I often cheat by sticking an Application.DoEvents() in the middle of the long running code which allows the GUI to service other requests like a button click that sets a global/form level scoped variable indicating cancelation. This can introduce all kinds of problems as the user can be clicking away all over the place messing up whatever is going on - or maybe even reentering the long running task. But if this is a simple utility that only you use I think cheating is OK.

Answer (score 0):

This code runs on the thread, different from your main application

```
private function LongRunningFunction()
    Din canceled as boolean  = false ' to make sure it is canceled while in the loop
    ' this is very long loop
    For i as integer = 0 to 100000
        If _cancelExecution Then
            canceled = true
            Exit For
        End If
        ' your code runs here
        .........
    Next

    If canceled Then 

        ' Wrap up this thread, clean up stuff, etc 
    End If
    .......................
End Function
```

On the main thread, when button is clicked `_cancelExecution` is set to true

The `BackGroundWorker` has this mechanism built-in already